# Remove some of trailing zeros from decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column `decimal(10,5)` — *VALUE*, and column `int` — *PICTURE*.

So, I need to **round** *VALUE* to *PICTURE* digits after decimal point.

For example:

- if `VALUE = 10.50000` and `PICTURE = 2`, I want to get `10.50`;
- if `VALUE = 0.15371` and `PICTURE = 3`, I want to get `0.154`

If I use just `Round()` or `Cast(Round(...) as nvarchar)`, then I have trailing zeros. If I `Cast()` to `float`, then I loose zeros.

Is there any solution?

Comment: This is something for your presentation layer, not the RDBMS. A Column can only have 1 data type, and that data type can't have varying scales, precisions and lengths. For a `decimal` column, if that column is defined as a `decimal(10,5)` it will **always** have 5 decimal places, even if none are needed. If you want a vary *display* value, get your display layer to handle that.

Comment: @Larnu, You are right. I should deal with this on presentation layer. But always want an easy solution, like get everything in one select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`str()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function with `trim()`:

```
select trim(str(value, 20, picture))
```

`str()` converts a number to a string with the specified length and precision.  Sadly, it produces a fixed length string, left padded with spaces.  The `trim()` removes the spaces.